# React Native with FlowType: Exporting and importing js interfaces

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, flowtype

I'm using FlowType on a React native project and I want to put a JavaScript interface in its own file for sharing throughout the project. Thoughts?

Comment: This is a broad question, what specific issue are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to use **export type** and **import type**.

I found the answer here:

https://flowtype.org/docs/modules.html#type-imports--exports